# How to pass the array object in $http.get method in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, json

I want to pass Array object in `$http.get()`. Previously all information is stored in `data.json` file, But I don't want to use file. Want to define the Array of  object as `$scope.data` in controller. 
Please find  **DEMO**
http://plnkr.co/edit/X5ZC3UGey4Zjos7W01U1?p=preview

Working DEMO http://plnkr.co/edit/o6EeKnC8oFEq3GCRsQgp?p=preview
 here we are using data.json. I want to define data inside data.json in Controller, Plz tell me how to dd

```
.controller('QuestionCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) { 
  $scope.questions = [];
  $scope.data =   {
  "questions": [
    {
      "question": "Qw1",
      "answers": [
        {
          "answers": "An1",
          "value": 25
        },
        {
          "answers": "An2",
          "value": 50
        },
        {
          "answers": "An3",
          "value": 75
        },
        {
          "answers": "An4",
          "value": 100
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "question": "Qw2",
      "answers": [
        {
          "answers": "An1",
          "value": 25
        },
        {
          "answers": "An2",
          "value": 50
        },
        {
          "answers": "An3",
          "value": 75
        },
        {
          "answers": "An4",
          "value": 100
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
  $http
    .get(JSON.stringify($scope.data))
    .then(function(response){
      $scope.questions = response.data.questions;
    });
}])
```

Comment: I do not get the question. What are you trying to achieve? Getting json with $http?

Comment: @Poyraz Please see the working examble plnkr.co/edit/o6EeKnC8oFEq3GCRsQgp?p=preview here we are using data.json. I want to define data inside data.json in Controller, Plz tell me how to do

Comment: as your json data and $http in one controller , then no need to use $http, you can directly get these json.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using this, and it works great for me

```
$http.get('url', {params: yourArray}).then(function (result) {
  //do sth with data
});
```

Comment: Please see the working examble plnkr.co/edit/o6EeKnC8oFEq3GCRsQgp?p=preview here we are using data.json. I want to define data inside data.json in Controller, Plz tell me how to do

Answer (score 0):

HTTP GET request can't contain data to be sent to the server. You can add a query string to the request. `$http` option for it is `params`.

```
$http({
    url: 'example.com', 
    method: "GET",
    params: {...}
 });
```

Comment: Please see the working examble http://plnkr.co/edit/o6EeKnC8oFEq3GCRsQgp?p=preview  here we are using data.json. I want to define data inside data.json in Controller, Plz tell me how to do

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to use $http.get() if the data is directly available in controller.

```
You can use $scope.data instead of $scope.questions. ie in your html file use
{{data.questions[0].question}}
<h2>answer 1</h2>
<p>{{data.questions[0].answers[0].value}}</p>
<p>{{data.questions[0].answers[0].answers}}</p>
```

Comment: BUt I need to use it.  
Please see the working examble plnkr.co/edit/o6EeKnC8oFEq3GCRsQgp?p=preview here we are using data.json. I want to define data inside data.json in Controller, Plz tell me how to do

Comment: In plnkr, you stored the data in $scope.data right? I dont understand what you mean "I want to define data inside data.json in Controller" because you define data inside data.json in your $scope.data already in the controller right?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this way and it is working fine:
For example in your controller you have any array like arr variable

```
var data = Array;
    data['Id'] = "1";
    data['Name'] ="Test User";
    data['UserName'] = "test_user";
    data['Email'] = "test@gmail.com";
    data['Address'] = "Test Address";
    data['Action'] = 'Create';
```

To pass this array you can use like this

```
$scope.users = data;
```

The controller send an array in view page as the variable `users`
and you can use something like this

```
ng-repeat="user in users"
```

Note: this will work for two dimensional array and one dimensional array.

Answer (score 0):

AngularJS has `$http` service, to get data asynchronously. So it can return any type of data(variable, array, string).

It is better to store data in some common place. Let me show **factory** pattern which is used for sharing data between controllers.

At first, you should create `yourFactory.js` file and write the following code:

```
(function () {    
    var yourFactory = function () {
        var persons = [
                {
                    id: 1,                    
                    name: 'Jon',                    
                },
                {
                    id: 2,                    
                    name: 'Ben',                    
                },
                {
                    id: 3,                    
                    name: 'Joseph',                    
                },
                {
                    id: 4,                    
                    name: 'Adam',                    
                }
        ];

        var factory = {};
        factory.getPersons = function () {
            return persons;
        };
        return factory;
    };

    angular.module('personsApp').factory('personsFactory', yourFactory);

}());
```

and some your controller can use data(just create new `.js` file for the following controller):

```
(function()
{    
    debugger;
    var yourController=function($scope, yourFactory) { 
                 /*alert('a1');*/
                 debugger;                 

                 function init() {
                    debugger;
                    $scope.yourData=yourFactory.getPersons();
                 }        
                 init();   
             };    


    yourController.$inject=['$scope', 'yourFactory'];   

    angular.module('yourAppl').controller('yourController', yourController);

}());
```